# Reputation page showing two upvote events for two answers on one question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

My reputation page shows two separate upvote events at the same time on the same post.

[image: My reputation page]

I think this is because if you look at [the post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848985/generate-data-in-excel-using-macros/), I made two answers to it and both of them have been upvoted at the same time (I suspect by someone who was trying to be kind and give me some rep by upvoting my answers on other posts after I helped him out in the comments on a different post entirely).

I think the upvote events for the two separate answers should be merged in the reputation view, listed as "2 events" with a little arrow to expand in the same way as the others shown there.

Answer (score 1):

It is by design. Because both are separate posts so it is showing separate.

Comment: OK, so you're saying this is a confusion over the term "post" which is overloaded to mean both "question" and "answer to question". In which case it would be nice if the reputation list said something like "Answer [id or timestamp] to Generate data in Excel using Macros" rather than just giving the question title.

Comment: @Vicky - I don't think adding id or timestamp will make any changes. Because when you hover on the post title it will show you post id (as a link). But still you can add your own feature request for that.